# File browser-like element in Mac OS programming of Xcode

Tags: xcode, cocoa, user-interface, browser, nssplitview

Sorry that my title is not clear enough. What I wanted to ask is based on a screen capture:
[image]

I want to make an app like this. But there are two elements I do not know what the classes are: A and B (C and D are NSSplitView. I just knew).

Could any one just tell me what ducuments to follow to create UIs like the appearance of A and B? Thank you!

Comment: Check out NSOutlineView for A.

For B, try NSToolbar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create A UI in [NSOutlineView](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSOutlineView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) is the way to display hierarchical data that can be expanded and collapsed, such as directories and files in a file system.

B is made by  [Gradient buttons](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSButton_Class/Reference/Reference.html) set images to gradient buttons to get B UI

or

Use [NSToolBar](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSToolbar_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to use formal ui design.